# Return Array of Eigen::Matrix from C++ to Python without copying

Tags: python, c++, numpy, eigen, pybind11

I have some C++ code that generates and manipulates arrays of `Eigen` matrices.
In the end I want to use those matrices in python and thought this might be a job for `pybind11`.

Basically what I want back in python are two nested lists / numpy arrays
`mat_a(I, 4, 4)` and `mat_b(J, K, 4, 4)`.
Because I have to do a lot of linear algebra stuff in C++ I wanted to use Eigen and the data structure I used is
`std::array<std::array<Eigen::Matrix4f, 2>, 3>>> mat_b  // for J=3, K=2`.
The problem now is how to get this to python efficiently?

Additionally I want to perform those calculations for multiple inputs **x** = [x_0, x_1, ..., x_N] and than expect `mat_a(N, I, 4, 4)` and `mat_b(N, J, K, 4, 4)` as result. The calculations  for each `x_i` are independent but I thought maybe it is faster to write this loop over `x_i` in C++ as well. If on the other hand the task gets easier if we only have fixed sized arrays in C++ this loop can also move to python.

Here is some dummy code of my problem (I=5, J=3, K=2) :

```
// example.cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/eigen.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/functional.h>
#include <pybind11/stl_bind.h>

#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Dense>


Eigen::Matrix4f get_dummy(){
    Eigen::Matrix4f mat_a;
    mat_a << 1, 2, 3, 4,
             5, 6, 7, 8,
             9, 8, 7, 6,
             5, 4, 3, 2;
    return mat_a;
}

std::pair< std::vector<std::array<Eigen::Matrix4f, 5> >,
           std::vector<std::array<std::array<Eigen::Matrix4f, 2>, 3> > >  get_matrices(std::vector<float> & x){

    std::vector<std::array<Eigen::Matrix4f, 5> > mat_a(x.size());
    std::vector< std::array< std::array< Eigen::Matrix4f, 2>, 3> > mat_b(x.size());

    //    for (u_int i=0; i< x.size(); i++)
    //        do_stuff(x[i], mat_a[i], mat_b[i]);
    mat_a[0][0] = get_dummy();

    return std::make_pair(mat_a, mat_b);
    }


PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.def("get_dummy", &get_dummy, pybind11::return_value_policy::reference_internal);
    m.def("get_matrices", &get_matrices, pybind11::return_value_policy::reference_internal);
}
```

I compile the code via:

```
c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++14 -fPIC `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` example.cpp -o example`python3-config --extension-suffix`
```

And than use it in python:

```
import numpy as np
import example

x = np.zeros(1000)

mat_a, mat_b = get_matrices(x)

print(np.shape(mat_a))
print(np.shape(mat_b))
print(mat_a[0][0])
```

If I just want to return a single `Eigen::Matrix` it works fast and as far as I can tell without copying. But when I try to nest the `Eigen:Matrices` with `std::array/std::vector` pybind returns a nested list of numpy arrays instead of one multidimensional array.
This is as expected and I am actually impressed how well this works but it seems rather slow to me especially as the dimensions of the arrays grow.

The question is how can I improve this to get multidimensional numpy arrays without unnecessary copying.

Some roads I tried but did not work (for me, what doesn't mean that they do not work in general; I just could not figure it out):

- use `Eigen::Tensor` instead of the arrays of `Eigen:Matrix`
- create the matrices in python and pass it to C++ by reference
- building a custom wrapper for array<array<Matrix4f, K>, J>

Comment: A `numpy` multidimensional array has a 1d data buffer, and uses `shape` and `strides` to handle the multidimensionality.  If you c++ structure does not have a compatible layout, you can't avoid the copy.  For example I believe often `c` matrices are an array of pointers to arrays.  That's more like the Python list layout.

Comment: A possible workaround could be to allocate a block of memory on the Python side (nd-array) and than creating multiple views/Maps (your matrices) to this homogeneous block of memory (with corresponding offsets) on the Eigen/C++ side and work with them there. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best option may be to create the data on python side so it gets refcounted and garbage collected.

**test.py**

```py
import example
import numpy as np

array = np.zeros((3, 2, 4, 4), 'f4')

example.do_math(array, 3, 2)
print(array[0, 0])
```

**example.cpp**

```cpp
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

#include <Eigen/Dense>

Eigen::Matrix4f get_dummy() {
    Eigen::Matrix4f mat_a;
    mat_a << 1, 2, 3, 4,
             5, 6, 7, 8,
             9, 8, 7, 6,
             5, 4, 3, 2;
    return mat_a;
}

PyObject * example_meth_do_math(PyObject * self, PyObject * args, PyObject * kwargs) {
    static char * keywords[] = {"array", "rows", "cols", NULL};

    PyObject * array;
    int rows, cols;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwargs, "Oii", keywords, &array, &rows, &cols)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    Py_buffer view = {};
    if (PyObject_GetBuffer(array, &view, PyBUF_SIMPLE)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    Eigen::Matrix4f * ptr = (Eigen::Matrix4f *)view.buf;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            ptr[i * cols + j] = get_dummy();
        }
    }

    PyBuffer_Release(&view);
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

PyMethodDef module_methods[] = {
    {"do_math", (PyCFunction)example_meth_do_math, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, NULL},
    {},
};

PyModuleDef module_def = {PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, "example", NULL, -1, module_methods};

extern "C" PyObject * PyInit_example() {
    PyObject * module = PyModule_Create(&module_def);
    return module;
}
```

**setup.py**

```py
from setuptools import Extension, setup

ext = Extension(
    name='example',
    sources=['./example.cpp'],
    extra_compile_args=['-fpermissive'],
    include_dirs=['.'], # add the path of Eigen
    library_dirs=[],
    libraries=[],
)

setup(
    name='example',
    version='0.1.0',
    ext_modules=[ext],
)
```

It should be trivial from here to add a second parameter and use the two arrays for the calculation.

You can build this with `python setup.py develop`.

if you want to distribute it you can create a wheel file with `python setup.py bdist_wheel`.

I used `numpy` to create the data, this ensures the underlying memory of the data is C contiguous.

This example was kept simple and it uses a Matrix4f pointer to iterate a 3x2 array of matrices. Feel free to cast the `ptr` to an `Eigen::Array<Eigen::Matrix4f>, 3, 2>`. You cannot cast it to an `std::vector` since the internal data of an `std::vector` contains a pointer.

Please note that `std::vector<std::array<...>>` does not have a single contiguous array in the memory. Use `Eigen::Array` instead.

**edit:**

Here is a function that uses an `Eigen` `Array` `Map`:

```cpp
PyObject * example_meth_do_math(PyObject * self, PyObject * args, PyObject * kwargs) {
    static char * keywords[] = {"array", NULL};

    PyObject * array;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwargs, "O", keywords, &array)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    Py_buffer view = {};
    if (PyObject_GetBuffer(array, &view, PyBUF_SIMPLE)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    Eigen::Map<Eigen::Array<Eigen::Matrix4f, 2, 3>> array_map((Eigen::Matrix4f *)view.buf, 2, 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            array_map(i, j) = get_dummy();
        }
    }

    PyBuffer_Release(&view);
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

Comment: It is possible to create a new type from C++ containing the data type you defined in C++ and do work with that, but due to eigen in array in vector structure of your type you never get it in a single numpy object. Even if you manage to define a type that is contiguous in memory calling `PyMemoryView_FromMemory` then `np.frombuffer`  would be "far" from simple.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works great and adding the second array was straightforward. Two things I wanted to ask. First could you spell out the cast from `ptr` to a `Eigen::Array`. And is it necessary to use a `setup.py` file or can I achieve the same using the right set of flags for the compiler? Or in general do you recommend (multiple) `setup.py` files for a bigger project because it can be better automated/ are there advantages?

Comment: I will edit the answer soon to use `Eigen::Array` it will take a bit of time since I never use Eigen. I prefer [glm](https://glm.g-truc.net/). When you call the `python setup.py develop` the compilation and linking steps are printed to the console.

Comment: You can get rid of the setup.py and use those commands in a makefile instead. I suggest keep the setup.py as per standalone parts of your big project. it comes really handy when smaller parts compile independently and can be unit tested as well. If you keep them as separate repositories tag versions accordingly and add a requirements.txt into your main project. Another option is git submodules. It is also possible to have a single setup.py and many `Extension`s in it.

Comment: Thank you again, those detailed explanations really do help. One last thing: how can I use rows and cols to set the dimensions of the array according to the input?

Comment: you cannot change template parameters at runtime. what you could use is "stride" I have seen Eigen supports custom strides for Map. look for alternatives of Array and Map. For me Eigens source is barley readable. create new questions regarding Map and Array. Eigen experts may help you.

Answer (score 1):

One other possibility if you're not too tied to Eigen is xtensor ( [found here](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor)). I've used their python bindings before which give an example of communicating directly with python([found here](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor-python)). This will have the advantage of being able to handle larger, multi-dimensional arrays. The linear algebra won't be as slick (hard to beat Eigen there), but will be similar to what you would do in numpy (`np.dot(A,B)` for example.

If you want to stick with Eigen, note there is some technical specifics with using the STL. As your `std::array` is no longer able to contain a fixed number of Matrices, when you move to `std::vector` you will hit alignment issues (admittedly, that I don't totally understand). Will get a working implementation of xtensor for you shortly.